# access to the registry key 'Global' is denied

Tags: xconnect

How to solve the XConnect:

```
2018-10-02 00:00:27.142 +02:00 [Information] SystemPerformanceCounters Constructor, Instance:xconnect, Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xconnect\App_Data\Diagnostics, CounterFilePattern: *.json
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.InternalGetValue(String name, Object defaultValue, Boolean doNotExpand, Boolean checkSecurity)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue(String name)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceData(String item)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CategoryExists(String machine, String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(String categoryName, String machineName)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.SystemPerformanceCounters.Initialize(String counterFilePattern)
```

Comment: Also note you need to restart AppPool related to xconnect after you apply @Harsh Baid solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the IIS app pool user to the "Performance Monitor Users" & "Performance Log Users" groups, e.g:

```
CMD> net localgroup "Performance Monitor Users" "IIS APPPOOL\sitecore" /add
CMD> net localgroup "Performance Log Users" "IIS APPPOOL\sitecore" /add
CMD> net localgroup "Performance Monitor Users" "IIS APPPOOL\xconnect" /add
CMD> net localgroup "Performance Log Users" "IIS APPPOOL\xconnect" /add
```

Comment: As it is an app pool user (and not a local user) prefix it with the group: `CMD> net localgroup "Performance Monitor Users" "IIS APPPOOL\sitecore" /add`

Comment: Bear in mind that there is a [known issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324639/net-exe-add-command-does-not-support-names-longer-than-20-characters) with names longer than 20 characters, so you might need to use the GUI the users :(

Answer (score 15):

I had to do the following steps to fix this issue.

1. Open "Computer management" > "Local Users and Groups" > "Groups" > "Performance Monitor Users" > *Now 'Add' the application pool user account* (example: `IIS AppPool\SiteName_xconnect.local`)
2. Do above step for `Performance Log Users` as well.
3. Restart AppPool for the XConnect website.

Notes:
1. I had also executed `Sitecore.XConnect.Diagnostics.InstallCounters.exe` under `[XConnect IIS Site Folder]\App_data\Diagnostics\` before doing Step #1
2. You might have to complete all of the steps listed above for `refdata` and `marketingautomation` IIS Websites as well. This depends on how Sitecore and XConnect is setup.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need performance counters enabled, you can shut the functionality off by finding all of the files called sc.PerformanceCounters.Initialize.xml in the XConnect web root and changing

```
<PerformanceCounters>Sitecore:XConnect:Diagnostics:PerformanceCounters:Windows</PerformanceCounters>
```

to

```
<PerformanceCounters>Sitecore:XConnect:Diagnostics:PerformanceCounters:Disable</PerformanceCounters>
```

After that you will need to restart your XConnect site(s) and the XConnect services.